# Network location In android 8.0 is not working

Tags: android, location, android-8.0-oreo

I have used the following code to get the network location .
With this code I'm getting the location in android 7.0 and below .
but above android 8.0 and above its telling to turn on the GPS 
Is there is any changes in the location settings

```
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET
            },10);
            return;
        }
    }
        else
        {
            configureButton();
        }

    }



    private void configureButton() {
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, locationListener);

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: check for the type of location that you have allowed in the settings , 
there are 3 types .  choose the the hight accuracy . it will give all permissions . .

Comment: @Hamza Khan .. high accuracy uses gps .. I don't want that I need it on network ..